# Buying bike parts from Chinese suppliers like Aliexpress

Tags: mountain-bike, fork, shopping

Are these forks any good considering the price?  You can find them extremely cheap on aliexpress. There aren't many reviews on youtube so what would be your opinion on it?

Is it too good to be true?

[AliExpress link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/ZOOM-680dh-downhill-bike-magnesium-alloy-suspension-fork-26-inch-mountain-bike-mtb-20MM-barrel-shaft/32812689013.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_1_10152_10065_10151_10068_10084_10083_10080_10082_10081_10110_10136_10137_10111_10060_10112_10155_10113_10114_10179_10154_10056_10055_10054_10182_10059_100031_10099_10078_10079_10103_10073_10102_10189_10052_10053_10142_10107_10050_10051,searchweb201603_1,ppcSwitch_5&btsid=cad20961-0cb1-47f8-8619-a271a3939c5c&algo_expid=bffeb6d5-97c1-4755-a32b-184b6fdf294c-33&algo_pvid=bffeb6d5-97c1-4755-a32b-184b6fdf294c)

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Do you really want to be trusting something that takes heavy hits to aliexpress retailers?

Comment: I don't plan on using it for actual downhill. Rather something like casual riding through woods with lots of bumps or bumpy roads and occasional jumps. Would a low-end Suntour (or rockshox, fox or any of the brand names) be better for this? I mostly like this one because it has a lot of travel (180mm)

Comment: I'd guess its going to bounce a lot. I'd be more comfortable with a low end suntour or rockshox just cause I know they build things properly. Though in the use case described, a rigid fork with big tires would probably be better.

Comment: Why rigid? Wouldn't I want softer so it absorbs more bumps and gives smoother ride?

Comment: 180mm is way to much for what you say you'll be doing, and on a cheaper fork such as that, a lot of your energy will be wasted bouncing that fork every time you pedal. A Suntour would more than likely suit you just fine ( minus any large jumps or hard landings, a rockshox or fox fork will be better quality overall but quite a bit more expensive as well. The option to lock out the front fork is always nice when on streets and smooth terrain as well.

Comment: "casual riding though woods and bumpy roads"  ?  You'd be perfectly happy with the normal front suspension you probably have on your bike now, and I'd do all that on a rigid bike.  If you want to ride a souped up-looking bike and not use it, that's called "posing/poseuring" or "ricing"   Honestly?  Ride your bike and let actions speak louder than appearance.

Comment: Trust me it isn't. [Here's an image off the internet.](http://pro.zapodaj.net/uploads/bike-system/1582/102__2_.JPG). It's almost as if there isn't any suspension on it. 

'casual riding though woods and bumpy roads' yes because there aren't any MTB trails/parks where I live. I would definitely use it in every way but it's not possible right now, until I move to a different town.

Comment: I've tried to make the question more generic and less of a shopping question about specific forks.

Comment: Rigid forks work fine on bumpy roads. Big tires, low tire pressure absorb bumps really well. And for the occasional jump, rigid is fine (in fact, might be better than the cheaper suntours and stuff).

Comment: You need to ensure the fork is compatible with your current bike. I suspect you have 9mm qr wheel and the fork you are asking about is 20mm thru axle, so the wheel won't fit. The steerer needs to match (1 1.8" or 1.5-1 1/8"tapered?) You will also need a head set (or remove the crown race from your existing fork).   Too good to be true - probably. Ali-Express is about 1/2 price compared to what I have to pay in my country for the same shock, but if I buy locally I get covered by consumer protection laws. "Too good to be true?"  probably, as you cannot send it back if its wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer - maybe.

The only advantage is the cheap price.

Downsides

- No warranty
- No idea if the build quality will duplicate what you see on the website
- if your fork fails, there is nothing to stop you face-planting.

**Teeth don't grow back**

Depending on your location, something like [this fork](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06W2MX4CN)   might be better.   At least if it fails you have someone more local to provide backup and support.

Comment: That looks like the same one I linked only on amazon. But anyways I saw it's a coil spring. I like air more because it's easier to adjust it (how soft/rigid it is, am I wrong?). I'm gonna go with suntour I read somewhere it's more cheaper than rockshox or fox but bit lower quality. It's still better than zoom, I already got a zoom fork just not this one and it's awful. Probably something like [this](https://www.amazon.de/Suntour-Federgabel-100mm-schwarz-Fahrradgabel/dp/B00BZ22SV6/ref=sr_1_22?s=sports&ie=UTF8&qid=1499764920&sr=1-22&keywords=sr+suntour) or [this](http://bit.ly/2uM6GpU)

Answer (score 3):

well, don't buy it.

- I'm Chinese, I wouldn't buy stuff there.
- unless you know the supplier
- a lot cheaper models from named brand are made in China, with decent quality, but they will not sell on this website normally.
- from my point view, zoom is garbage

Comment: Ok. I decided to go with suntour forks.

Comment: There are also lots of counterfeit products on that website, so even buying something that claims to be a named brand is no guarantee of quality

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure about those exact ones, but I've seen a guy in the city with Zooms, he's happy. Not sure why, since they're crap, but certainly better than low end suntours (which are the equivalent of strapping an extra 2kg to your bike and getting worse performance than rigid) note that some of the nicer suntours, when you go past the 3 letter XCR XCM etc which are all useless, are actually great value forks which I would happily ride.

Also: you want 180mm double crown forks? Is your frame even compatible? Do you understand how it's going to change the geometry of your bike?

Answer (score -1):

I think that this video explains it quite clearly...

Cheers

Comment: While it looks like a relevant link, its in German and has no subtitles.  While its unlikely that youtube will vanish from the internet, its always possible for links to expire.  So to get around that, we like for answers to contain a summary of the link so the answer remains useful if the link does die.

Comment: Suspected translation:  "We bought a cheap double crown fork and fitted it to a bike.  Then tested it outside in the carpark.  It survived that so went for a ride with jumps."  The text at the end says "Conclusion:
For the price okay
Unfortunately, the heavy downhill use is extremely heavy and very easy to break through.
The tension regulator works as well as not at all, if you are not careful, the landing can very rudely go forward.
Among other things, she had extremely fallen after a few departures."  Roughly means its okay for poseuring but any real use will not survive.

Comment: Yes of course, I apologise...In the video the guy buys the fork just for laughs and later abuses it as it were the fox 40. In the beggining it shows as the fork has little or no rebound damping and the fork is loud and clicky from the start. By linking the video here I meant to say that do not buy this fork even if it seems as a good deal, you’re better off gettinga used rockshox domain dual crown or something similar.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. [We prefer answers on this site to be self-contained](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). That way, the answer is still valid if the link dies. Please use the edit button to summarize the information is contained in the video within the body of your answer. Otherwise, it is likely to be downvoted, flagged for moderator intervention, and possibly deleted.

Answer (score -3):

I don't know about this fork, but I bought a SRAM nx 1x11 setup from them about a year ago - it looks like the real thing, it works amazingly well, and it was very inexpensive.

I imagine this fork is a bit of more a gamble, but it's not an expensive one. If you got spare money that you can afford to lose, try it out. Have fun with it.

Comment: It's not an expensive gamble if the fork breaks. The problem is that, when forks break, parts of the rider tend to break, too...

Comment: What's a benjamin?  Is it jargon for risking your teeth in a crash ?

Comment: @Criggie https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_one_hundred-dollar_bill#/media/File:Obverse_of_the_series_2009_$100_Federal_Reserve_Note.jpg. And yes, I would save gambling on bike parts with something that fails more gracefully.